# How to download csv files from a json file which contains the url to the csv files?

Tags: python, json, csv, urllib

I am running a file which downloads a json file which contains the url to multiple csv files. It looks something like that.

```
{"data_files":
{"i_p":["https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_i_p.1_0.1.csv.gz",
"https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_i_p.1_0.2.csv.gz"],
"c_p":["https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_c_p.1_0.1.csv.gz",
"https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_c_p.1_0.2.csv.gz"]},
"date":"2021-05-05"}
```

Now I want to download all the files in the json file. I am using the following code.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
import urllib
import datetime

myResponse1 = requests.get('https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user.json?api_key=xxxxxxxxx&personal_key=xxxxxxxx')

if(myResponse1.ok):
    file = open("V.json", "wb")
    file.write(myResponse1.content)
    file.close()
    
    
file = open('V.json', 'r')
id = 0
for line in file:
   response = urllib.request.urlretrieve(line, str(id) + '.csv')
   id+=1
    
else:
  # If response code is not ok (200), print the resulting http error code with description
    myResponse1.raise_for_status()
```

The above code is able to download the json file but I am not sure how to use the json file to download the csv files stored inside the json.Can someone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: the json is missing a bracket, please provide a working json sample.

Answer (score 0):

had to play around with your json, but if you can get it to a point where you iterate over the key/value pairs, use requests to download the files

```
data = '''{"data_files":
{"i_p":["https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_i_p.1_0.1.csv.gz",
"https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_i_p.1_0.2.csv.gz"],
"c_p":["https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_c_p.1_0.1.csv.gz",
"https://dashboard.s.com/api/1/user/downloads/2021-05-05/all_2021-05-05_c_p.1_0.2.csv.gz"]},
"date":"2021-05-05"}'''

dataj = json.loads(data)

for k,v in dataj['data_files'].items():
    for f in v:
        print(f)
        r = requests.get(f, allow_redirects=True)
        print(f.split('/')[-1]) # split out the file name
        open(f.split('/')[-1], 'wb').write(r.content) # write the file
```